# Translation of Zend_Validation in ZF2

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-validate

I have a strange Problem in Zend Framework 2. I've used the Zend Skeleton Application (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) and added PhlyContact as Vendor Module (https://github.com/weierophinney/PhlyContact). I changed the Translation-Type to PhpArray so that i can use the Zend_Validate.php located in the resources-dir of the ZF2-Dist.

Everything translates EXCEPT the validation Messages :/ So i guess i am missing something:

- I must pass the Translator to Zend_Validate (but how and where?)
- The Translation should use a Text-Domain, but doesn't

When i remember right in ZF1 you had to set the Translator to default to pass it to Zend_Validate. Any Ideas on that !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at these methods

```
\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator();
\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslatorTextDomain();
```

Comment: Thanks, right way, but i wanna have it in the Module Application that does not contain a Form or Validation. I thought the best way to set the DefaultTranslator would be the Module-php - though - ZF2 won't le me ...

Comment: @gmuehl you can do it in any module as all modules are beeing bootstrapped

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this with only one line (2nd parameter is text domain):

`AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator, 'default');`

Example within Module.php:

```
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class Module 
{

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) 
    {
        $translator = ....
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator, 'default');
    }
}
```